# как убрать отступ в div

Tags: html, css

как убрать отступ? перерыл по интернета не помогло
вот размтека:

```css
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 348px;
  height: 63px;

  font-family: 'Leckerli One', cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 54px;
  line-height: 86px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  color: #F34A4A;

  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.foot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 87px;

  background: #222F34;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Leckerli+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="foot">
          <h1 class="logo">BaseSec</h1>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Какой отступ хотите убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть отступ в body. Добавьте в css

```
body{
 margin:0;
}
```